# How to develop for MRP (Mythroad, platform for chinese mobile application)?

Tags: java-me

Hello dearest community

I just given a task to develop a mobile application for chinese mobile phone, Nexian  NX-G920. At first, I think it can just run the J2ME application. But it didn't, it only support MRP application. Having read about it here : [MRP](http://en.sky-mobi.com/technology-mp.html), I think my best case is, if any, convert my *.JAR application into *.MRP. Is there any tool that can do it?

My Plan B is, to develop using specific MRP SDK. But that is just to costly, in term of effort  to be use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found one solution, but I have to use my C languages, not the plain J2ME as first I thought it will. Here is the SDK, [Open SDK](http://skysdk.51mrp.com) by Sky Mobi.

Haven't try it though, but I think this is one solution that fit the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are only Java to C translators or Java bytecode to assembly translators like those listed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941244/compiler-to-translate-java-bytecode-to-platform-independent-c-code-before-runtim).

These include JCGO, Toba, gcj and llvm. However a Java to C translator or similar is only part of the solution because it would only help you if you were translating classes that didn't interact with Java libraries that are not part of the MRP platform. This is because MRP platform won't have the libraries you link to and will have different GUI and hardware API calls than J2ME.

The only SDK for MRP is the [OpenSDK](http://skysdk.51mrp.com/) which you have already mentioned.

Comment: The link to the question is really useful for me. Before searching this kind of converter tool, I quite pessimistic of the result. Yet, there are work for that kind of tool. 
Yes, I see that I must use OpenSDK, and forget my intention of using J2ME

Answer (score 0):

Sky-Mobi SDK is saved this archive on Wayback Machine
The Sky-Mobi is saved this page of site in the Internet Archive